# Acesso negado ao utilizar MS SyncFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, sincronização

Estou tentando implementar um sistema onde preciso ter um banco de dados local (SQL Compact) e um na nuvem (MSSQL) que possam ser sincronizados. A forma que encontrei e que estou seguindo é a especificada nesse [link](http://www.systenics.com/blog/sync-sql-server-2012-data-with-sql-ce-35-sp2-over-the-internet-using-wcf-services-using-ms-sync-framework-v21/?tag=Sync%20Framework%20v2.1).

Porém estou com alguns problemas quando hospedo o serviço WCF em um servidor dedicado (no IIS da minha máquina está funcionando).

O erro encontrado é o seguinte:

**ExceptionDetail**, provavelmente criado por **IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true**, cujo valor é:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {EC413D66-6221-4EBB-AC55-4900FB321011} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).    at Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncIdFormatGroup.get_ProviderSyncServices()

Alguém já passou por um erro parecido? Ou conhece uma maneira mais simples de implementar isso?

Answer (score 1):

**Relativamente ao erro**

O mais provável é o IIS estar a tentar carregar uma das bibliotecas da SyncFramework que não está instalada no servidor.

Experimente instalar/reinstalar o [`redistributable`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19502) no servidor (x86/x64 dependendo do seu servidor).

**Alternativa à SyncFramework**

Uma alternativa à SyncFramework é utilizar o [SSIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) (Sql Server Integration Services).

O SISS oferecem interface gráfica que pode utilizar para desenhar o que está a tentar fazer (e o pacote dos SISS pode correr comandos SQL para resolver problemas de duplicação/conflitos de dados, etc). Pode depois colocar agendar o pacote para correr num SQL Server Job quando necessário.

*(opinião pessoal a partir deste momento)*

Utilizei ambas as tecnologia, mas muito mais SyncFramework e o problema que enfrentei é o *overhead* técnico necessário para criar e manter uma solução feito com esta *framework*.

Se tiver oportunidade, explore a ideia do SSIS e tendo em conta que o suporte para esta funcionalidade é maior que para a SyncFramework.

Comment: Tentei reinstalar na versão do servidor e o erro continua. Tentei, também, a alternativa respondida nesse forum: [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/dafb776e-4501-4c9a-857d-7431f7e14d9a/access-is-denied-syncframework?forum=wcf] e também nada. Vou realizar mais algumas tentativas e estudar o SSIS para ver o que posso fazer aqui.

Comment: Que versão instalou, x86 ou x64? Algumas vezes, apesar do servidor ser x64, a SyncFramework procura bibliotecas x86 (devido a referências erradas no projecto). Experimente instalar ambas as versões (x64 e x86) e veja se o erro persiste.